# How to skip webpack-internal generated code while debugging in Visual Studio Code React Typescript or NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js, vscode-debugger

Visual studio code debugger is stepping into webpack-internal generated source files while debugging NextJS Typescript. Visual studio code `launch.json` is

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
 
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug client-side",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**",
        "<node_internals>/**/*.js",
        "<node_internals>/**/*.mjs",
        "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
        "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.mjs",
        "${workspaceFolder}/.next/**/*.js",
        "${workspaceFolder}/_next/**/*.js",
      ],
 
    }
  ]
}
```

`tsconfig.json`  file is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "out",
    ".next"
  ]
}
```

[image]

tokenService.ts is generated by webpack. It is hard to understand and debug the code.

I tried few options given in stackoverflow answers but it is not working

Comment: Did you figure it out?  It's been driving me crazy for over a year.  I've tried everything I've googled with no luck.

Answer (score -1):

Add `"**/webpack-internal://**"` to your `skipFiles`.

Comment: This does not work for me.  It still breaks within the webpack file. Any other suggestions?

Comment: this worked for me. sorry I misclicked the downvote button. can you please edit the answer so my downvote gets unlocked, I want to upvote.